# Question about rational exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From a book, the question goes like this:

This is how John simplified $\sqrt[3]{16x^5}$.
$\sqrt[3]{16x^5} = \sqrt[3]{8} \ \cdot \sqrt[3]{2x^5} = 2\sqrt[3]{2x^5}$ 
Explain the mistake in John's work and then correct it.

My answer: Isn't John correct? I mean,
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{16x^5} & = \sqrt[3]{(2\cdot 8)\cdot x^5} \\
 & = (2\cdot 8 \cdot x^5)^{1/3}\\ 
 & = 2^{1/3}\cdot8^{1/3}\cdot x^{5/3} \qquad \text{from $(xy)^n = x^ny^n$ }\\ 
 & = 8^{1/3}\cdot2^{1/3}\cdot x^{5/3} \qquad \text{just rearranging}\\ 
 & = \sqrt[3]{8} \cdot (2x^5)^{1/3}\\
 & = \sqrt[3]{8} \cdot \sqrt[3]{2x^5}  \qquad \text{which is the same with John's answer}\\
 & = 2\sqrt[3]{2x^5}
\end{align}

Am I missing something here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: John  may not have exactly made a mistake.  However, did he completely simply the expression?

Comment: @S.A.Lloyd yeah, you're right. I might be overthinking the "mistake".

Comment: Fwiw, I dislike the wording "mistake".  But to simplify it you should do it completely.  You should *not* have gone back from $8^{\frac 13}\cdot 2^{\frac 13}\cdot x^{\frac 53}$ back to $\sqrt[3]8 \cdot(2x^5)^{\frac 13}$.  Also you need to put the powers of $2$ together.  Your next step should be $2\cdot 2^{\frac 13} \cdot x^{\frac 53} = 2^{\frac 43}x^{\frac 53}$.... but I'd be *loathe* to call your work a "mistake".

Comment: In general don't split common bases; you have to put them back in the end anyway. $\sqrt[3]{16x^5} =\sqrt[3]{2^4 x^5} = 2^{\frac 43}x^{\frac 53}$ is about as fast and as clear as you can get.

Comment: Not sure what is expected as "simplified", but clearly there is no mistake per se.  Perhaps the expected answer was $2x\,\sqrt[3]{2x^2}$ or $2^{4/3}x^{5/3}$ both of which are extremes of different views of what's "simpler".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was an educator for 20 years, teaching mathematics at the secondary level throughout my career.  Working from that context, and assuming the book in question was a high school mathematics textbook (perhaps Algebra 2), the John was mistake was leaving $x^5$ within the radical.

From a high school algebra student, the simplify for would be achieved as follows.

$$\sqrt[3]{16x^5}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{8\cdot 2\cdot x^3\cdot x^2}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{8x^3}\sqrt[3]{2x^2}$$
$$2x\sqrt[3]{2x^2}$$
While writing the expression using rational exponents would be correct, high school students and their textbooks generally do not use rational exponents.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is what does the autor consider to be a simplified expression. John didn't made any mistake, but someone would say that a more simplified expression would be
$\sqrt[3]{16 x^5} = 2^{(\dfrac{4}{3})} \cdot x^{(\dfrac{5}{3})}$.

Comment: Though your solution is correct, the use of rational exponents is not expected route in secondary mathematics.  However, it is expected that variable expressions are extracted from radicals to what ever degree is possible.